# Submenu not visible even with zindex

Tags: css

The submenu is not displaying upon hover. I'm not exactly sure which part of it went wrong. Previously, I was able to get my submenu to show up when display:none is being removed. But I wanted the submenu to show when I hover across that menu item. Thanks.

```
#navigation ul li a:hover { 
background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
display: block;
}

#navigation ul li ul {
position: absolute;
top: 58px;
left: 0px;
width: 200px;
border: none;
z-index: 1200!important;
background: #D32828;
display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to say without seeing your HTML, but presumably you want to change:

```css
#navigation ul li a:hover { ... }
```

To:

```css
#navigation ul li a:hover + ul { ... }
```

Otherwise you're only setting the `a` element to `display: block` on hover, *not* the `ul` element.

Comment: Wouldn't placing the hover event on the li and the subsequent display:block on the child ul suffice? Since when you mouseout from the a href, the ul falls back to display:none.

Answer (score 1):

Might as well give it as an answer:

#navigation ul li:hover > a { 
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  }
  #navigation ul li:hover ul { 
  display:block;
  }